Handling large amounts of data efficiently in a MEAN stack application while ensuring data consistency can be challenging
I am facing technical issues with handling a large amount of data in my MEAN stack application. To avoid repeatedly calling the API, I have implemented local storage to cache the data. If the same data is needed again, it is retrieved from local storage instead of calling the API. However, the problem arises when the data in the database gets updated. Since the application retrieves data from local storage, it does not reflect the updated data from the database. How can I handle this scenario effectively?
I am expecting that someone solved this issue!!

A strategy of cache invalidation is what you need to solve this problem. Here are some strategies:

TTL (Time to Live): Set TTL for cached data in local storage. After the TTL expires get fresh data from API and update the cache.
Versioning: Put version or time stamp in cached data. When you get data compare with its version; if cache’s version is outdated get latest data from API.
Background Sync: Use a background process or service worker to periodically check server for updates and refresh cache if it has changed.
WebSockets: This involves sending updates from server to client through WebSocket whenever there is a change in the database, hence synchronizing the cache with the database.

